# How to get only List of all properties of User through Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am working on CRUD operation of User on Azure AD. I will use Java to handle it.
My requirement is I want one Graph API reference or any other utility through which I will get list of Users all properties like 'accountEnabled', 'displayName', 'mailNickname', 'userPrincipalName' ,'passwordProfile' .... there are so many.

I am trying to get from below API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata
```

But here, I am getting huge data in which User properties are also present.
Below is piece of response from above API:

```
<EntityType Name="user" BaseType="microsoft.graph.directoryObject" OpenType="true">
        <Property Name="accountEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
        <Property Name="ageGroup" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="assignedLicenses" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.assignedLicense)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="assignedPlans" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.assignedPlan)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="businessPhones" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="city" Type="Edm.String" />
```

likewise there are so many  tags

Can anyone know how to get it?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$metadata` document has a list of all entities like users and groups and I don't think there's a way to scope it down to just users. If you're not interested in parsing it, maybe look at the Graph SDK and use reflection? The SDKs are generated from the Graph metadata so for example the Java SDK has all these properties on the `User` class - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/graph/models/generated/BaseUser.java#L201

You can check the microsoft graph github organization page for SDKs in other languages.